# Are non-Muslims evil according to Islamic belief?

Tags: tafseer

One of the answers to the question [Is Satan evil or just doing his job?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/8149/is-satan-evil-or-just-doing-his-job) makes the point that Satan was once a believer, but became a disbeliever, which seems to imply that non-believers are "evil". It's an interesting point because I was under the impression that there is no compulsion within Islam to convert to Islam, [Surah 2. Al-Baqara, Ayah 256](http://www.alim.org/library/quran/ayah/compare/2/256/there-is-no-compulsion-in-religion-and-wali-of-allah-vs-wali-of-shaitan).

Are non-Muslims evil according to Islamic belief?

Answer (score 6):

Islam makes abundantly clear that mankind has great potential for good (e.g. ["We have certainly created man in the best of stature"](http://quran.com/95/4)). Muslims are commanded to behave and dialogue in the best manner possible with Muslims and non-Muslims alike, and therefore the question of the inherent evilness of non-Muslims does not arise. The people Muslims most look up to after the Prophet (saws) - his Companions (raa) - were mostly disbelievers before becoming Muslim. They were not inherently evil prior to that, and they weren't treated that way except if they were doing evil actions.

Nowhere in the texts does it say that a person is inherently evil because of disbelief, and based on the generality of texts outlining the opposite, one would need some pretty solid proof to assert otherwise.

In Islam we don't ascribe the qualities of good or evil to a person as a permanent label. Rather, this is determined by beliefs and actions. Someone who commits evil actions is evil when s/he commits them, but this doesn't mean that their actions will always be evil. Committing unjust and oppressive actions is evil regardless of whether the person is Muslim or not. Persisting in the rejection of God when the truth is clear to a person is an evil deed indeed - however the resolution of this situation is between him/her and God, not upon the Muslims.

Finally, being evil or not has nothing to do with conversion. Muslims are obliged to deliver the message, not to convert people.

Comment: But if someone reads the Quran and decides there is no reason to believe what's written there, is that person evil in the eyes of Muslims? Are there passages in the Quran which guide Muslims on this matter?

Comment: Why would they be evil? Where is this coming from? That person's disbelief, like I said, is between them and God. Muslims don't know what's in their heart - whether they are rejecting the message out of arrogance or an incomplete picture or whatever else. I don't understand the leap between disbelief and evilness. Like I said in the answer, evilness or goodness is primarily attributed to actions.

Answer (score 0):

Islam does not call to hatred of infidels or non-Muslims, on the contrary, he advocated charity for them it is some examples

1 - protection of that request in the event of war even heard the word of God

2 - charity to them and that charity Messenger of Allah Jewish neighbor and he was drop dirt in front of his house and when he did drop he go to see him

3-Even while in Mecca was Allah bless him and when God sent the king of the mountains to assist him and salm take revenge  said no hoping that God comes out from them body who yabd of God and do not engages anything with Him As 
And much more

And if you talk about enmity, or intimidate non-Muslims now they think that Islam is a religion of jihad and fighting and Jihad does not called without any reason, but in the case of hostility or prevention of made people hears about Islam only or who want to fight us, he said prayed God upon him to on because Allah guides one man better for you than red camels Fargo me and for all guidance

And Further Reading Read the biography of the Prophet, peace be upon him
for the meaning of the verse is abrogated in this link but it in arabich ttp://vb.tafsir.net/tafsir5997/ if you realy want to read Quran you must lurn arabic 
And finally I ask aalah to make all of us muslimm to enter his gna what non- muslim call it Paradise